# JS/AngualarJS/Jquery/CSS Minimize Maximize Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am trying to understand how to make my current 'modal' code allow for a minimize and maximize button where the modal would minimize to the bottom of the screen when clicking the - button and in the little rectangle at the bottom allow for clicking the + button to bring it back.

Basically I want it to work the same as a browser where you minimize things to the bottom of the desktop, but in this case our application.

**HTML**

```
<button id="phq_btn" ng-click="openModalBtn('phq_modal','modal-overlay')">PHQ Open Modal</button>




<div id="modal-overlay">


          <!--PHQ Modal-->
          <div id="phq_modal" class="modal">
            <!-- PHQ Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <!--Allow Scroll-->
              <div class="modal-scroll">
                <!--Allow Dragging of Header-->
                <div class="modal-header">
              <div layout ="row" class="titleHolder" style ="height: 25px; width: 100%" >
                <div layout="column" flex="33">PHQ-9</div>
                <div layout="column" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255)" layout-align="end end" flex="100"><span ng-click="closeModalBtn('phq_modal','modal-overlay')" style="margin-bottom:7px" class="close">&times;</span></div>
              </div>
            </div>

          
CONTENT GOES HERE.
          
             
          </div>
              </div>
              </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 999; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    z-index: 999;
    /*
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity 
    */

  }
  
  /* Modal Content/Box */
  .modal-content {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 70%;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
    pointer-events:all;
    z-index: 999;
  }

    /* Modal Scroll Content*/
.modal-scroll {
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    pointer-events:all;
    }

    .modal-header{
    cursor: pointer;
    }
  
  /* The Close Button */
  .close {
    color: #f7f3f3;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    pointer-events:all;
  }
  
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .modal-overlay-on {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: opacity 200ms;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
  }
```

**JS**

```
//Open Modal
$scope.openModalBtn = function(modal,overlay){ 
eval(modal + '.style.display = "block"');
eval("$('#" + overlay + "').addClass('modal-overlay-on')");
};

//Close Modal
$scope.closeModalBtn = function(modal,overlay){ 
eval(modal + '.style.display = "none"');
eval("$('#" + overlay + "').removeClass('modal-overlay-on')");
};

//Drag Modal
$(".modal").draggable({
    handle: ".modal-header"
});

//Disable Click outside of Modal
window.onclick = function(event) {  
    if (event.target == phq_modal) {
    phq_modal.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

Comment: where is your code for minimizing the modal?

Comment: Why those `eval`? It's useful to know that a lite version of jQuery is already natively present in angularJS, accessible with the [angular.element( yourSelector )](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). For example `angular.element('#" + overlay).addClass('modal-overlay-on');` should work straight out of the box, without adding jQuery

Comment: @cloned That's why I am here to figure out where to start with the code that I have for my modal currently.

Comment: @kaddath.   I am using jquery 1.11.1.min and angularjs 1.7.2

Comment: That was the point of my comment, you are not really supposed to add jQuery to AngularJS, it is already included inside (a light version)

Comment: @kaddath  interesting.  Thank you.  Now I just need to figure out how to make these modals minimize haha

Comment: Yep sorry I don't really have time these days for complex answers, I'll take a look later if not answered

Comment: @Kaddath.  Totally understand.  Thank you!  Happy Holidays :)